# Upper bound on zero multiplicity of Dirichlet $L$-functions

Tags: complex-analysis, l-functions

I was wondering whether there is (a known) upper bound of the order of the non-trivial zeros of Dirichlet $L$-functions. For a zero $s$ of the Riemann zeta function we have the estimate $C\cdot\log(\operatorname{Im}(s))$ where $C$ is some positive constant
([Do we know an upper bound for the multiplicity of the non-trivial zeros of Zeta?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144093/do-we-know-an-upper-bound-for-the-multiplicity-of-the-non-trivial-zeros-of-zeta)).

For the non-trivial zeros the order should be $1$, based on the fact that the gamma function has simple poles at the negative integers (derived from the [functional equation for those $L$ functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_L-function#Functional_equation)).

An estimate similar to that of the zeta function would be rather helpful to show the convergence of a series ranging over the reciprocals of the (non-trivial) zeros squared! (counting multiplicity :P)

Comment: The same holds for $L(s,\chi)$ (it follows from the asymptotic density of zero). With $O(q \log Im(s))$ instead of $O(\log Im(s))$ the result should be uniform in $\chi$ and $s$. Your series is $\sum_\beta \frac{1}{|\beta|^2}$ ?

Comment: Thats awesome! :) Thank you! Any chance you have a citation I could use in a paper?

Comment: The series is $\sum_{p} \frac{m(p)}{\vert{p}\vert^2}$ where $m(p)$ is the multiplicity of p :)

Comment: In the series over the non-trivial zeros, the zeros of order $m$ are repeated $m$ times so it is what I wrote : $\sum_\beta \frac{1}{|\beta|^2}$. Do you see why an upper bound for the density of zero $\# \{ |Im(\beta)| < T\} < A \ T^b$ with $b < 2$ is enough to show it converges ?

Comment: I don't know simple references for Dirichlet L-functions. Search for Selberg class or L-function + density of zeros. Iwaniec&Kowalski's book has the detailed proof of the uniform results.

Comment: I'm assuming $\#{{\vert{Im(p)}\vert < t}}$ is the size of ${\vert{Im(p)}\vert < t}$ ? Assuming that: I don't see it right now. I tried to make an estimate with $\vert{t}\vert\le \vert{p}\vert$ : $\sum_{p} \frac{m(p)}{\vert{p}\vert^2}\le\sum_{p} \frac{At^b}{\vert{p}\vert^2}\le\sum_{p} \frac{a*\vert{p}\vert^b}{\vert{p}\vert^2}=A \sum_{p} \frac{1}{\vert{p}\vert^\epsilon}  for some  \epsilon > 0 $. Which diverges.

Comment: $\# \{ |Im(\beta)| < T\} < A \ T^b$ means the $n$-th zero satisfies $|Im(\beta_n)| > \frac{n^{1/b}}{A}$ so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{|\beta_n|^2} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{A^2}{n^{2/b}}$ which converges for $b < 2$. The well-known result is with $T \log T$ instead of $T^b$.

Comment: Oh ok! I had no clue what this # is... in that case it's quite clear! A little bit of $\zeta$ going on there. Thanks! :) Would be very nice of you to provide a link to the Wikipedia page of the #. Sorry for the hassle, still in the first semester of my studies xD

Comment: $\#$ is a common notation for the number of elements in a set

Comment: Never saw that before. Either way: how exactly do you get from $\#({\vert{Im(\beta}\vert <T}) < AT^b$ to $\vert{Im(\beta)}\vert > \frac{n^{1/b}}{A}$?

Comment: You assumed the simplicity of the non-trivial zeros right?

Comment: No. Again, the zeros of order $k$ are repeated $k$-times in the series over the zeros. That's why we have the explicit formula $\sum_{p^k < x} \log(p) = x - \sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}-\log (2\pi)/2$ no matter of the order of the zeros.

Comment: I assume you defined $\# \{\vert{Im(\beta)}\vert < T \} := o$ then rewrote $o < AT^{1/b}$ to get $\frac{o^{1/b}}{A'}<T$. Together with $T<\vert{Im(\beta)}\vert$ which directly follows from the definition of $o$: $\frac{o^{1/b}}{A'}<\vert{Im(\beta)}\vert$. => In that case you aren't allowed to sum over $o$ from 1 to $\infty$, because you don't know if for all $n \in \mathbbm{N}$ there exists a $T$ such that $n=\# \{\vert{Im(\beta)}\vert < T\}$.

Comment: Where did you see a sum over $o$ ? You should take a look at derivations of the Riemann explicit formula $$\sum_{p^k < x} \log(p) =\frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty} \frac{-\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) \frac{x^s}{s}ds = \sum Res(\frac{-\zeta'}{\zeta}(s) \frac{x^s}{s})= x - \sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}-\frac{\zeta'}{\zeta}(0)$$ where we know $\sum_\rho \frac{x^\rho}{\rho}$ converges from the density of zeros $\# \{\vert{Im(\rho)}\vert < T \} \simeq C T \log T$ (a consequence of the functional equation) and the residue theorem is allowed again by the functional equation

Comment: You summed over all $o$ in one of your posts (Oct 2 at 19:47) you called it $n$ instead of $o$.